# Sharepoint Online MySite look and feel

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile, my-site

We are using O365/Sharepoint Online 2013.

As I've been searching different kinds of information and guides about configuring and modifying Sharepoint, I've come across many screenshots of the user MySites and almost everyone has the profile picture in the left corner (on top of the quick launch) but in our SPO MySites the profile picture is smaller and it is located on the upper border area right next to the quick launch.

So I wondered if it can be simply changed which layout to use or if it has been modified by Microsoft at some point (some of the screenshots I've seen are from the end of '13 and the beginning of this year).

EDIT: Here are screenshots to help visualize the question better.

The kind of MySite layout I've been seeing everywhere:
https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-lwz-U6XKcjo/UM5CA5_22NI/AAAAAAAAGOY/JN5DCOsnsbc/s640/SharePoint2013_MySite1.gif

The look of our MySite layout:
[image]

Thank you in advance for any information on this matter! :)

Comment: Are you using custom master page on My Sites? The positions may vary if the master page isn't (close to) the default mysite15.masterpage.

Comment: Nope, it's the default masterpage. I can get a screenshot and add it to my post to show how our mysites are looking. :P

Comment: I once had it looking exactly like this and it definitely was about the master page in my case, so there ends my suggestions based on my experiences :(

Comment: Ok that's strange as I haven't touched the MySite masterpage. Still thanks for your info! I'll keep searching and see if someone else knows how to switch it to the another look. :)

Comment: To get back the old look, you'd need to create custom mysite host master page.

Comment: @Aveenav do you mean that the new and current official look should be like in the screenshots of our MySites? If that's correct, I wonder why Microsoft changed it as the old one looked better in my opinion. :)

Comment: Yes, that's the new look. There are additional changes too, now your profile picture appears on the suitebar, before your login name.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for the info! Somehow none of our users have their pictures in the suitebar yet. Slow rollout maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The look and feel in your screenshot is the new look and feel of the mysite. Microsoft did some changes to the look and feel of SharePoint Online. These updates were deployed during summer of 2014.

To mimic the old look and feel, you can create a new master page and CSS file and deploy these to all your mySites. However there is no guarantee that your changes will continue to work after future updates to SharePoint Online. In fact with all the upcomming changes in SharePoint with "Onedrive for Business" and "Yammer" I expect the mysite to change quite frequently.

My advise is: embrace the changes that Microsoft did. Try limiting your branding on the mysites to only coloration/CSS changes. Keep in mind that the mysite has no publishing features enabled by default and that for every user within your SharePoint a new Site Collection is created. This makes deployment of custom look and feel a bit harder.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I actually lately figured out that this is the case and we decided to leave the MySites unbranded. The new custom theming feature helps a bit so now we can set the color of the Suite Bar and set our own Suite Bar logo & link at least! Anyways, as this is the fact I'll mark your answer as correct. Take care! :)